# Unable to click on overflowing elements outside of div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to replicate angular material select but having a some trouble with positioning and events.

https://jsfiddle.net/eptcjssy/

I've got a parent div

```
.fancy-select-container {
position: relative;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
width:434px;
text-align: left;   
display:block;
height:35px;
}
```

and a child div

```
.fancy-select-container .list-container{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
max-height:200px;
background-color:white;
}
```

and then a list within the child div whose height is greater than the parent div since it's a list.

The problem is that I'm only able to click/hover the first list item because it's inside the parent div height. I tried playing around with z-indexes but didn't get much joy. How do I make it so that the overflowing part receives events as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you need to apply the ".list-item" class to all items in the list.

Example fiddle.

```
<li class="list-item">1</li>
<li class="list-item">2</li>
<li class="list-item">3</li>
<li class="list-item">4</li>
<li class="list-item">5</li>
<li class="list-item">6</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agvxqge6/

Comment: Gah! Tunnel vision is a horrible horrible thing. Thank you.